# Email application mutilingual support implementation

Tags: email, jsp, servlets, character-encoding

I am building an email application using JSP and servlets in which I will be receiving mails in almost all languages (multilingual). How do I get those mails in the same format as they are sending without modifying the content to some Unicode (Polish->Polish,French->French and not in some Unicode). Is there any language encoding had to be done in my JSP? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you better explain what you're after? Can you control which character sets your users are sending you? Asking them politely to use UTF-8 or BIG-5 or Koi-8 or whatever might just do the trick. What problem are you _really_ trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Just read the mail content in *their own* encoding into a `String` and then display all of those `String`s in Unicode (UTF-8 is recommended). Java by default already stores characters of a `String` in Unicode format (UCS-2 actually). Javamail by default already returns mail content in the proper encoding as `String`, you don't need to explicitly specify anything. You just have to tell the JSP to send the response as UTF-8 and tell the browser to interpret it as UTF-8. This can be done on a per-JSP basis by just the following line in top of JSP:

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: Apparently the cause of the problem is in how you're reading the mail messages. Are you using Javamail?

Comment: No, Iam getting the mail as a string which contain the mail content as an HTML...!!!!

Comment: That doesn't matter. What if you debug-print this string to the logger/stdout? Does it look all right? (note that the logger/stdout must by itself also be configured to use UTF-8!)

Comment: In log, I am also getting the mail thing, but I am not sure that its configured as UTF-8

Comment: You are not entirely clear on "getting the mail thing", but I understand that all mails looks fine in there? Well, then the cause of the problem must be sought in the way how you sent it to JSP and how you printed it in the JSP and how the JSP response encoding is been set. How exactly are you sending it to JSP and printing there?